# Varnish GeoIP (vmod_geoip) + Amazon Linux

Tags: linux, varnish, geoip, amazon-linux

I'm trying to install vmod_geoip via amazon linux, but so far no luck.

I've installed geoip geoip-devel.  I've downloaded the vmod_geoip source.  I'm able to ./autogen.sh but ./configure constantly halts at:

```
No package 'geoip' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables libGeoIP_CFLAGS
and libGeoIP_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
```

This package seems to have issues specifically on Amazon Linux, elsewhere works fine. I've tried customizing paths, but that doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out amazon's rpm doesn't install the pkg-config files.  I ended up building everything from source (including varnish) and manually setting up the environmental variables.

This is technically a live bug with GeoIP 1.4.8.